# Submit button does not work reloading the page or submitting the form MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, model-view-controller

After select values from the dropdownlist and click submit button, the submit button could not submit the form or reloading the page. I have the form tags on the code but it couldn't work. The submit button cannot either reload or submits. When I clicked the button, nothing response. I am using MVC.
Please please please help me. I need to this done as soon as possible and I cannot figure it out. I really appreciate if you can please help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is the html code:

```
 <div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("WACCTest", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "nameform" }))
                {
                    <div>
                        <form>
                            <table id="tbl_posts">
                                <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
                                    <tr id="rec-1">

                                        @*BW: These is the dummy data for the keywords selection, when the sql is ready to linked to the model. These will be  deleted*@
                                        @*BW: The following are my dropdownlists*@
                                        @{
                                            Model.KeywordOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();

                                            Model.KeywordOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "--Select Option--",
                                                Value = "selectoption1",
                                            });

                                            Model.KeywordOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Market Cap",
                                                Value = "TEST 1",
                                            });
                                            Model.KeywordOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Revenue",
                                                Value = "TEST 2"
                                            });
                                            Model.KeywordOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Keywords",
                                                Value = "TEST 3"
                                            });
                                        }

                                        @{
                                            Model.MarketandRevenueOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();

                                            Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "--Select Option--",
                                                Value = "",
                                            });

                                            Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Greater Than",
                                                Value = "Test 4",
                                            });
                                            Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Less Than",
                                                Value = "Test 5"
                                            });

                                            Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Equals",
                                                Value = "Test 6"
                                            });

                                            Model.MarketandRevenueOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Range",
                                                Value = "Test 7"
                                            });
                                        }

                                        @{
                                            Model.KeywordsList = new List<SelectListItem>();

                                            Model.KeywordsList.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "--Select Option--",
                                                Value = "Test 8",
                                            });

                                            Model.KeywordsList.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Excluding",
                                                Value = "Test 9",
                                            });
                                            Model.KeywordsList.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Including",
                                                Value = "Test 10"
                                            });

                                            Model.KeywordsList.Add(new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = "Exact Phrase",
                                                Value = "Test 11"
                                            });

                                        }

                                        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.KeywordOptionsSelected, Model.KeywordOptions, new { @id = "Dropdown_TEST" })</td>

                                        <td class="display" style="display:none; text-align:left; width:18px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MarketandRevenueOptionsSelected, Model.MarketandRevenueOptions, new { @id = "platt" })</td>


                                        <td class="display_1" style="display:none; text-align:left; width:18px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.KeywordsListSelected, Model.KeywordsList, new { @id = "platt2" })</td>


                                        <td class="display_2" style="display:none; text-align:center;">
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="number" name="keywordtextbox" value="0">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="display_3" style="display:none; text-align:left;">
                                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                                <input type="text" name="keywordtextbox" placeholder="e.g Toy Manufacturing">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>


                            <div style="display:none;">

                                <table id="sample_table">
                                    <tr id="">
                                        <td>
                                            <select required id="Dropdown_clone">
                                                <option value="selectoption_clone">--Select Option--</option>
                                                <option class="cont" value="clone 1"> Market Cap</option>
                                                <option class="cont_1" value="clone 2"> Revenue</option>
                                                <option class="cont_2" value="clone 3"> Keywords</option>

                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="display_clone" style="display:none;">
                                            <select required id="platt_clone">
                                                <option value="">--Select Option--</option>
                                                <option value="clone 4"> Greater Than </option>
                                                <option value="clone 5"> Less Than </option>
                                                <option value="clone 6"> Equals </option>
                                                <option value="clone 7"> Range </option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="display_1_clone" style="display:none; text-align:left; width:10px">
                                            <select required id="platt2_clone">
                                                <option value="clone 8">--Select Option--</option>
                                                <option value="clone 9">Excluding</option>
                                                <option value="clone 10">Including</option>
                                                <option value="clone 11">Exact Phrase</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="display_2_clone" style="display:none;">
                                            <div style="text-align:right;">
                                                <input type="number" name="keywordtextbox" value="0">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="display_3_clone" style="display:none;">
                                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                                <input type="text" name="keywordtextbox" placeholder="e.g Toy Manufacturing">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>


                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record" data-added="0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Row</a>
                            </div>

                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <input type="submit" name="theForm" id="theForm" value="Apply" /><br />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
```

As you can see I have the httpget of @using (Html.BeginForm("WACCTest", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "nameform" })). This usually works, but I have no idea why  the form cannot be submitted.

Here is the model:

```
    public List<SelectListItem> KeywordOptions { get; set; }
    public int KeywordOptionsSelected { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> MarketandRevenueOptions { get; set; }
    public int MarketandRevenueOptionsSelected { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> KeywordsList { get; set; }
    public int KeywordsListSelected { get; set; }
```

Here is the Controller:

```
public ActionResult WACCtest(string RegionID1, bool HongKong = false, bool China = false, bool marketmultiples = false, bool dcf = false)
        {
            var objWACC = new WACC();
        XmlDocument xmlTmp = webS.GetWaccOptionsIndustries();
        objWACC.Industries = new List<Industry>();

        XmlDocument nodeCompsTmp = webS._Test_CompsFilter();
        objWACC.Companies = new List<ComparableCompanies>();

        XmlDocument nodeMktRevenueTmp = webS._Test_MktCapRevenue();
        objWACC.MrkCapRevenue = new List<MrkCapAndRevenue>();

        XmlNodeList nodeListMktCap1 = nodeMktRevenueTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Mkt_Cap");
        XmlNodeList nodeListRevenue = nodeMktRevenueTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Revenue");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeListMktCap1.Count; i++)
        {
            MrkCapAndRevenue objMktCapRevenue = new MrkCapAndRevenue();
            objMktCapRevenue.Mrk_Cap = double.Parse(nodeListMktCap1[i].InnerText.Trim());
            objMktCapRevenue.Revenue = nodeListRevenue[i].InnerText.Trim();

            objWACC.MrkCapRevenue.Add(objMktCapRevenue);
        }

        XmlNodeList nodeListCompID = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Company_ID");
        XmlNodeList nodeListCompName = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Company_Name");
        XmlNodeList nodeListStockTicker = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Stock_Ticker");
        XmlNodeList nodeListIPO = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("IPO_Date");
        XmlNodeList nodeListCompWeb = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Company_Website");
        XmlNodeList nodeListCompDescr = nodeCompsTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Company_Description");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeListCompID.Count; i++)
        {
            ComparableCompanies objComparableComps = new ComparableCompanies();
            objComparableComps.Company_ID = int.Parse(nodeListCompID[i].InnerText.Trim());
            objComparableComps.Company_Name = nodeListCompName[i].InnerText.Trim();
            objComparableComps.Stock_Ticker = nodeListStockTicker[i].InnerText.Trim();
            objComparableComps.IPO_Date = DateTime.Parse(nodeListIPO[i].InnerText.Trim());
            objComparableComps.Company_Website = nodeListCompWeb[i].InnerText.Trim();
            objComparableComps.Company_Description = nodeListCompDescr[i].InnerText.Trim();

            objWACC.Companies.Add(objComparableComps);
        }

        //EC: add the columns one by one
        XmlNodeList nodeListGICCode = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("GIC_Code");
        XmlNodeList nodeListIndName = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Industry_Name");
        XmlNodeList nodeListIndLvl = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Industry_Level");
        XmlNodeList nodeListParentGICCode = xmlTmp.GetElementsByTagName("Parent_GIC_Code");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeListGICCode.Count; i++)
        {
            Industry indTemp = new Industry();
            indTemp.GIC_Code = int.Parse(nodeListGICCode[i].InnerText.Trim());
            indTemp.Industry_Name = nodeListIndName[i].InnerText.Trim();
            indTemp.Industry_Level = int.Parse(nodeListIndLvl[i].InnerText.Trim());
            indTemp.Parent_GIC_Code = 0;
            if (indTemp.Industry_Level != 1) { indTemp.Parent_GIC_Code = int.Parse(nodeListParentGICCode[i].InnerText.Trim()); }  //EC: no need to check the parent if industry level = 1 since it has no parent (will result an exception for level 1)

            objWACC.Industries.Add(indTemp);
        }


        string strValDate = Request.QueryString["ValuationDate"] ?? "2020-01-01";
        string strIndustrySelected = Request.QueryString["IndustrySelected"] ?? "0";     // BW: the selected varaables are based on index value
        string strLocationSelected = Request.QueryString["LocationSelected"] ?? "1";
        string strFV = Request.QueryString["FairValue"] ?? "0.0";
        string strRFR = Request.QueryString["RiskFreeRate"] ?? "0.0";
        string strBETA = Request.QueryString["Beta"] ?? "0.0";
        string strMRPs = Request.QueryString["Mrp"] ?? "0.0";
        string strCAPM = Request.QueryString["CAPM"] ?? "0.0";
        string strTAXRATE = Request.QueryString["TaxRate"] ?? "0.0";
        string strLendingRate = Request.QueryString["LendingRate"] ?? "0.0";
        string strWE = Request.QueryString["WE"] ?? "0.0";
        string strWD = Request.QueryString["WD"] ?? "0.0";
        string strAFTaxCod = Request.QueryString["AFTaxCod"] ?? "0.0";

        string strBetaSelected = Request.QueryString["BetaSelected"] ?? "0";
        string strMrpSelected = Request.QueryString["MrpSelected"] ?? "0";

        string strSizePr = Request.QueryString["SizePremium"] ?? "0.0";
        string strCompSpecPr = Request.QueryString["ComSpecPr"] ?? "0.0";
        string strLendRatePr = Request.QueryString["LendRatePr"] ?? "0.0";

        string strOtherPr = Request.QueryString["OtherPr"] ?? "0.0";

        string strIndustries = Request.QueryString["Industries"] ?? "0";

        string strKeywordOptions = Request.QueryString["KeywordOptions"] ?? "0";

        string strKeywordsSelected = Request.QueryString["KeywordOptionsSelected"] ?? "TEST 2";

        string strMarketandRevenueOptionsSelected = Request.QueryString["MarketandRevenueOptionsSelected"] ?? "0";

        string strKeywordsListSelected = Request.QueryString["KeywordsListSelected"] ?? "0";


        //BW: Define variable as double interger for the selecting Values
        int intIndSel = 0;
        int intLocSel = 0;
        double dblFV = 0.0;
        double dblRFR = 0.0;
        double dblBeta = 0.0;
        double dblMRP = 0.0;
        double dblCAPM = 0.0;
        double dblTAXRATE = 0.0;
        double dblLendingRate = 0.0;
        double dblWE = 0.0;
        double dblWD = 0.0;
        double dblAFTaxCod = 0.0;
        int intBetSel = 0;
        int intMrpSel = 0;
        string[] strVD = new string[3];
        DateTime dtVD = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01);
        List<string> listIndustry = new List<string>();

        int intKeywordsSel = 0;

        int intMarketandRevenueOptionsSel = 0;

        int intKeywordsListSel = 0;



        //BW: This is the User Input specific double interger
        double dblSP = 0.0;
        double dblCSP = 0.0;
        double dblLRP = 0.0;
        double dblOPR = 0.0;

        try { intIndSel = int.Parse(strIndustrySelected); } catch { intIndSel = 0; } //EC: add 1 to take into account of the default item 
        try { intLocSel = int.Parse(strLocationSelected); } catch { intLocSel = 0; }
        try { dblFV = double.Parse(strFV); } catch { dblFV = 0.0; }
        try { dblRFR = double.Parse(strRFR); } catch { dblRFR = 0.0; }
        try { dblBeta = double.Parse(strBETA); } catch { dblBeta = 0.0; }
        try { dblMRP = double.Parse(strMRPs); } catch { dblMRP = 0.0; }
        try { dblCAPM = double.Parse(strCAPM); } catch { dblCAPM = 0.0; }
        try { dblTAXRATE = double.Parse(strTAXRATE); } catch { dblTAXRATE = 0.0; }
        try { dblLendingRate = double.Parse(strLendingRate); } catch { dblLendingRate = 0.0; }
        try { dblWE = double.Parse(strWE); } catch { dblWE = 0.0; }
        try { dblWD = double.Parse(strWD); } catch { dblWD = 0.0; }
        try { dblAFTaxCod = double.Parse(strAFTaxCod); } catch { dblWD = 0.0; }
        try { intBetSel = int.Parse(strBetaSelected); } catch { intBetSel = 0; }
        try { intMrpSel = int.Parse(strMrpSelected); } catch { intMrpSel = 0; }
        try { dblSP = double.Parse(strSizePr); } catch { dblSP = 0.0; }
        try { dblCSP = double.Parse(strCompSpecPr); } catch { dblCSP = 0.0; }
        try { dblLRP = double.Parse(strLendRatePr); } catch { dblLRP = 0.0; }
        try { dblOPR = double.Parse(strOtherPr); } catch { dblOPR = 0.0; }

        try { intKeywordsSel = int.Parse(strKeywordsSelected); } catch { intKeywordsSel = 0; }

        try { intMarketandRevenueOptionsSel = int.Parse(strMarketandRevenueOptionsSelected); } catch { intMarketandRevenueOptionsSel = 0; }

        try { intKeywordsListSel = int.Parse(strKeywordsListSelected); } catch { intKeywordsListSel = 0; }


        //BW: For testing purpose add data to list 
        try
        {
            listIndustry.Add("Consumer Discretionary");
            listIndustry.Add("");

        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }


        try
        {
            strVD = strValDate.Split('-');
            dtVD = new DateTime(int.Parse(strVD[0].ToString()),
                int.Parse(strVD[1].ToString()),
                int.Parse(strVD[2].ToString()));
        }
        catch
        {
            //dtVD = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31);
            dtVD = DateTime.Now;
        }





        List<SelectListItem> tmpabc = new List<SelectListItem>();
        tmpabc.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "--Select Location--", Value = "2" });
        tmpabc.AddRange(webS.GetWaccOptionsOpLocations());
        resetValuesInListOfSelectListItem(tmpabc);
        objWACC.LocationList = tmpabc;

        List<SelectListItem> tmpbeta = new List<SelectListItem>();
        tmpbeta.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "--Select Beta--", Value = "2" });
        tmpbeta.AddRange(webS.GetWaccOptionsBeta());
        resetValuesInListOfSelectListItem(tmpbeta);
        objWACC.BetaList = tmpbeta;

        List<SelectListItem> tmpmrp = new List<SelectListItem>();
        tmpmrp.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "--Select Mrp--", Value = "3" });
        tmpmrp.AddRange(webS.GetWaccOptionsMRP());
        resetValuesInListOfSelectListItem(tmpmrp);
        objWACC.MrpList = tmpmrp;


        //BW: return a varible that have the values that user select or input from the UI
        objWACC.IndustrySelected = intIndSel;
        objWACC.LocationSelected = intLocSel;
        objWACC.FairValue = dblFV;
        objWACC.RiskFreeRate = dblRFR;
        objWACC.Beta = dblBeta;
        objWACC.Mrp = dblMRP;
        objWACC.CAPM = dblCAPM;
        objWACC.TaxRate = dblTAXRATE;
        objWACC.LendingRate = dblLendingRate;
        objWACC.WE = dblWE;
        objWACC.WD = dblWD;
        objWACC.AFTaxCod = dblAFTaxCod;
        objWACC.BetaSelected = intBetSel;
        objWACC.MrpSelected = intMrpSel;

        objWACC.SizePremium = dblSP;
        objWACC.ComSpecPr = dblCSP;
        objWACC.LendRatePr = dblLRP;
        objWACC.OtherPr = (objWACC.SizePremium + objWACC.ComSpecPr);

        objWACC.KeywordOptionsSelected = intKeywordsSel;
        objWACC.MarketandRevenueOptionsSelected = intMarketandRevenueOptionsSel;
        objWACC.KeywordsListSelected = intKeywordsListSel;

        string strOpLocation = objWACC.LocationList[intLocSel].Text;
        //string strIndustry = objWACC.IndustryList[intIndSel].Text;
        string strIndustry = "";

        string strBeta = objWACC.BetaList[intBetSel].Text;
        string strMRP = objWACC.MrpList[intMrpSel].Text;



        string strIndustrylevel = objWACC.Industries.ToString();
            
        }
        return View(objWACC);



    }
```

Here is my JavaScript for the Dropdownlist that uses show and hide:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //evaluate when the dropdown changes
        $('#Dropdown_TEST').on('change', function () {
            //reset everything to visible
            $('.display').hide();
            $('.display_1').hide();
            $('.display_2').hide();
            $('.display_3').hide();



            //if you do not have a value, ignore
            if (this.value.trim()) {
                if (this.value == 'selectioption1') {
                    $('.display').hide();
                }
                //hide first display if it should not be shown
                if (this.value == 'TEST 1') {
                    $('.display').show();
                    $('.display_1').hide();
                }
                //hide the second display if it should not be shown
                if (this.value == 'TEST 2') {
                    $('.display').show();
                    $('.display_1').hide();
                }
                if (this.value == 'TEST 3') {
                    $('.display_1').show();
                    $('.display').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //evaluate when the dropdown changes
        $('#platt').on('change', function () {
            //reset everything to visible
            $('.display_1').hide();
            $('.display_2').hide();


            //if you do not have a value, ignore
            if (this.value.trim()) {
                //hide first display if it should not be shown
                if (this.value == 'Test 4') {
                    $('.display_2').show();
                }
                //hide the second display if it should not be shown
                if (this.value == 'Test 5') {
                    $('.display_2').show();
                }
                if (this.value == 'Test 6') {
                    $('.display_2').show();
                }
                if (this.value == 'Test 7') {
                    $('.display_2').show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //evaluate when the dropdown changes
        $('#platt2').on('change', function () {
            //reset everything to visible
            $('.display_3').show();
            $('.display_1').hide();


            //if you do not have a value, ignore
            if (this.value.trim()) {
                //hide first display if it should not be shown
                if (this.value == 'Test 8') {
                    $('.display_1').show();
                    $('.display_3').hide();
                }
                //hide the second display if it should not be shown
                if (this.value == 'Test 9') {
                    $('.display_1').show();
                    $('.display_2').hide();
                    $('.display_3').show();
                }
                if (this.value == 'Test 10') {
                    $('.display_1').show();
                    $('.display_2').hide();
                    $('.display_3').show();
                }
                if (this.value == 'Test 11') {
                    $('.display_1').show();
                    $('.display_2').hide();
                    $('.display_3').show();
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

[This is how the dropwdownlist with the apply button look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYYcN.png)
So if I click apply nothing happens, doesn't reload the page or submitting anything, the page just sits there.

Please help me and review my code. I really appreciate if you can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the browser console? is it showing any error?

Comment: hey thanks for the comment, there is no error at all at the console.

Comment: So i after i delete the line   using (Html.BeginForm("WACCtest", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "TheForm" })) and put form tags on the submit button it can reload the page. but why? I thought you need   using (Html.BeginForm("WACCtest", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "TheForm" })) in order the form to be submitted

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: On my code it has the line @   @using (Html.BeginForm("WACCtest", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "TheForm" })) but when I delete this line and click the applu/submit button it can reload the page. Because before the page could not reload and not responding at all when submit button is clicked. How can I submit the form back to the controller ?

Comment: Please help me, i really need help? please

Comment: change to FormMethod.Post and Burton type to submit

Comment: return View(objWACC); if every goes correctly you will redirected o objwacc view btw view usually are in double qoutes and if you want to redirecttoaction us that

Comment: now I understand you try to pass an object to a view in the return call ok where is your strongly type?

Comment: it post backs but after return from controller it tries to parse sent object and fails

Comment: For pleasure of angels of code please do not use same view for  insert and showing data mvc is not singlepage

Comment: or at least use ajax

Comment: Thanks for the information @AlirezaMadad